# timer that makes a rerender every second - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a quiz app and wanted to attach a timer to each question that lasts 10 seconds and resets whenever new question is displayed. I end up doing this:

```
 const [timer, setTimer] = useState(10);

 useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (timer > 0) {
        setTimer((prevState) => prevState - 1);
      }
      if (
        timer === 0 &&
        currentPage + 1 < questions.length
      ) {
        setCurrentPage((prevState) => prevState + 1);
        setTimer(10);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timer]);

  
 console.log("component rerendered");
```

The fact that im worried about is that the component rerenders each second and i dont know if that constant rerendering is a good thing. Is there a better way to do this or its alright?

Comment: Your approach is correct, just keep it in a separate component and use props to interact with it from the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, in every 10 second you have to do a task which is this I guees

```
  setCurrentPage((prevState) => prevState + 1);
```

initiate `useRef`

```
  let setPageRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setInterval>>();
```

write your logic to run inside useEffect

```
 const startInterval = () => {
    setPageRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentPage((prevState) => prevState + 1)
    // This is 10 seconds
    }, 10000);
  };
```

inside `useEffect` call `startInterval` function

```
useEffect(() => {
    startInterval();
    return () => setPageRef.current && clearInterval(setPageRef.current);
  }, []);
```

1- `useEffect` has [] dependency means run this code everytime page rerenders.

2- We set up `setInterval` timer for 10000 which means its callback will run every 10 seconds, it will call `useState` which will update the state and rerender the app which will trigger `useEffect`. Insead of rerendering your app each second, now you will rerender in every 10 second

3- this will be a continuous interval setting. Based on your app I think you will be redirecting user to a different page and the timer will automatically will be cleared out inside `useEffect`.

4- You need to stop the interval when you hit the last question. You track the condition with this

```
currentPage + 1 < questions.length
```

so inside `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(currentPage + 1 < questions.length){
         startInterval();
    }
  return () => setPageRef.current && clearInterval(setPageRef.current);
      // you dont have to pass questions.length (since it is constant I guess) but react will warn 
      }, [currentPage,questions.length]);
```

Comment: I didnt  mention but im working with typescript and it throws me an error for ```setPageRef.current```  ```Type number is not assignable to type undefined```

Comment: I tried applying type for ```useRef```:  ```useRef<ReturnType<typeof setInterval>>()``` but then useEffect throws an error ```Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'void | { [UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY]: never; }'```

Comment: is your other `useState` config correct.